# Strange behaviour with DateFormatter: Inconcsistent times

Tags: swift

I am using `swift` on `Version 12.0 (12A7209)` of Xcode

I use a little function to format dates as strings:

```
private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
public func dateAsString(_ date:Date) -> String {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"
    return dateFormatter.string(from:date)
}
```

When I pass call it: `dateAsString(Date())` at 2021-01-06 14:28 NZDT it outputs: `2021-01-06 01:28:21.726`  Ok, it is using GMT.  But a few hours ago at about 12:05 NZDT on 2021-01-06 it gave me: `2021-01-05 11:05:20.014`.  That would be correct (in GMT) if it had `pm` appended...

Seems to me this is a fundamental that I must have done something incorrect.  Apple would not(?) get this wrong in a library.  So what is my mistake?

Comment: `hh` means 12-hour time. _You_ are responsible for adding the "pm" (using the format specifier `a`), or use `HH`, which is 24-hour time.

Comment: Yay!  A silly mistake.  Thank you